# Changing code in node_modules does not work in hot reload regardless of the bundler

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, google-chrome-devtools, vite

So I've been trying to debug library code **(@mui/material)** in a sandbox project in Chrome, but it doesn't work with either Vite or CRA - placing a console.log or debugger line inside library code (yes, I tried build folders of other libraries too) does not work. On the other hand, setting breakpoints on the same code in DevTools DOES work. WHat is the issue here, can it be hardware or something else I am misusing?

Comment: Please share your code and webpack config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically talking about Webpack which is used by CRA, it makes assumption that `node_modules` is not changed by the application. It is only meant to be changed by package managers (npm, yarn, etc.) during installation process.

In case of HMR, it generate a snapshot of your filesystem (keeping files in memory) for performance reasons. You can opt-out of this by using [`snapshot.managedPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#managedpaths) property:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...other configuration
  snapshot: {
    managedPaths: []
  },
};
```

Read [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11612#issuecomment-705790881) for further details on why it is not recommended.