# Vite - how to change code in node_modules folder to debug/find errors

Tags: node-modules, vite

Coming from Webpack I was able to change code in the `node_modules` folder in order to add a `console.log` statement or something like this to find errors.
Sometimes I use external libraries incorrectly and it's easier to be able to alter lines/files in the `node_modules` folder to find out what my mistakes are.

With Vite, this is not possible. I can change whatever I want in the `node_modules` folder by my browser still uses the original libraries code.
Is there a way that allows me to change files so Vite will recognize the changes and use my new files?

Note: it's not about pull requests or permanent changes, it's only about an `console.log(typeof X)` and stuff like that for a single use.

Bascially the same question as this one [Changing code in node_modules does not work in hot reload regardless of the bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73977086/changing-code-in-node-modules-does-not-work-in-hot-reload-regardless-of-the-bund)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Dep Pre-Bundling

According to [archive.org:vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20230122200251/https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html) it's not called "caching" but rather "dep pre-bundling" - y'know, because we wouldn't want the average Joe's search terms to work now would we?

### Delete Vite Cache

```bash
rm -rf ./node_modules/.vite
```

### Reload Dev without Vite Cache

```bash
rm -rf node_modules/.vite; npm run dev
```

### Monkey Patch Away

I was pulling my hair out trying to debug a dependency that needed a PR and doing dumb stuff like republishing `vite-shim-foobar` because I couldn't find the cache, but... I found it. So now I can monkey patch to debug things too!

Comment: Thank you, `--force` flag wasnt working for me and I was losing my mind!

Answer (score 19):

Restart Vite dev server with the `--force` flag to re-bundle the deps. This has the same effect as manually deleting the `node_modules/.vite` directory.

See [File System Cache](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#file-system-cache) in [Dependency Pre-Bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you, this works, but I always have to restart the bundler for any change. But at least this way I'm able to include a log

Comment: Note you may also need to force-clear your browser cache.